# AdSense responsive format resizable on the fly

Tags: google-adsense, responsive-webdesign

The [AdSense responsive format](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124) sizes the advertising only on load. If the user resizes the window (from large to small), the advertising is not resized (even with media queries) and keeps its initiale size. It seems that [we are only allowed](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124#hide) to `display: none;` it.

Is there a way (compliante with the TOS) to resize it dynamically?

If not, is it possible (TOS again) to add `overflow: hidden;` so that we do not see that (the right border of the parent "box"):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com) and [resize event](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) to reload adsense code after the user resizes the window.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   reloadAdsense();
});
```

In order to prevent a problem with Adsense TOS, make sure it is reloaded with some delay.

```
$(function() {
    var resize;
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        clearTimeout(resize);
        resize = setTimeout(function() {
            reloadAdsense();
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible without tos violation: [this how-to](https://web.archive.org/web/20160324182143/http://abueg.org/posts/making-your-google-adsense-ads-really-responsive) explains the JQuery-based way.

Comment: It's always a good idea to add more details to an answer if possible. In this case the link is gone.